# get the exit message to use it with an object's __destruct method

Tags: php, exit

```
$fooinstance = new foo();
/*do something*/
exit('bar');

class foo{
  __destruct(){
    //get the exit message ("bar") to do something with it
  }
}
```

Hello,

I would like to get the exit message to do something with it (for example insert the exit status in a database). Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text `exit` sends isn't special; it's just [text that's output before the script dies](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/Zend/zend_vm_def.h?revision=302110&view=markup#l4502).

You could get the text with output buffering, though I'm not sure it'll be useful:

```
<?php
$fooinstance = new foo();
ob_start();
exit('bar');

class foo{
  function __destruct(){
    $c = ob_get_contents(); //$c is "bar"
  }
}
```

It would probably be best to wrap the exit instruction in a function that did the appropriate logging.

Comment: This is correct... it enables to both get the exit message (with all the output that happened before it) and echo everything after the ob_get_contents() to the normal output.
Yep, I also need some data outputted to the normal output, and at the same time get the die() message...
This method can take a lot of memory depending on the string outputted.

Answer (score 0):

This is an incorrect way to do things. Why do you need this particular solution?

Comment: the class I'm writing uses another one that has 'die("foobar")' when there's something wrong. I want to generate a proper report to say why it fails.

Comment: You need to replace this die() in that class with something like "throw new Exception('Error reason');" and just catch this exception in your outer class. http://us.php.net/exceptions.

Comment: Yep, that's the proper way. I should blast people who uses "die()" in their class, especially as they are essential to the program to run ok.

Comment: But I guess an other way would be to fork the use of the other class in another process, and in a way get its output : string buffering, put the buffered string in a file and get the content of the file with the parent process or something like that.

Comment: Forking processes from PHP only to get result from another script is an another bad idea, sorry ;)